# Why I can not split by space?

Tags: python

Here is the string:

```
u'\u041a\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0438\u043b\u044c\u043d\u0438\u043a\u043e\u0432 \u0421\u0435\u0440\u0433\u0435\u0439 \u0410\u043b\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0430\u043d\u0434\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0438\u0447'
```

if I try to `.split()` that, it doesn't work - just one part is returned. What can be wrong here?

Upd. full code:

```
page = urllib.urlopen('http://www.rea.ru/Main.aspx?page=Krasil_nikov_Sergejj_Aleksandrovich')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), fromEncoding="utf-8")
full_name = soup.find('div', {'class': 'flagPageTitle'}).text.strip().split()
self.response.out.write(str(full_name) + '<br>')
```

Comment: Hmm works for me, maybe you can post more code?

Comment: I'm getting all three parts by using split(). Show us your code please.

Comment: It splits for me.  If `s` is your string, did you check len(s.split).

Comment: Works for me on Python 2.6.5. `len(s.split()) ==3`

Comment: Would you please provide more information about what exactly you expect? I just tried this in a python interpreter and was able to get a list of 3 elements when calling split() on that string.

Comment: i recommend splitting your code into individual method calls rather than combining them all into one line, until you are more comfortable with the various methods. In other words, put `s = temp_string.split()` on a single line, then follow it with `len(s)` to determine if that is really your error.

Comment: @kmote, I've tried that. Everything works fine except split.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah.  See, the key was in information that you didn't post until requested.  Your string isn't what it looks like:

```
[u'\u041a\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0438\u043b\u044c\u043d\u0438\u043a\u043e\u0432&nbsp;\u0421\u0435\u0440\u0433\u0435\u0439&nbsp;\u0410\u043b\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0430\u043d\u0434\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0438\u0447']
```

where instead of spaces, it's `"&nbsp;"`, which is the non-break space character.  There are several stackoverflow questions about the best way to remove these; I don't know enough to know which one is best.

[IOW, search for "BeautifulSoup nbsp".]

Comment: Thanks. Somehow when tested with `self.response.out.write(` these characters were replaced with normal spaces. When looked thru Chrome console, they were also replaced.

Comment: @julio.alegria: thanks for the edit, I couldn't figure out how to suppress it becoming a space.

Answer (score 2):

I run your code and I got:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> import urllib
>>> page = urllib.urlopen('http://www.rea.ru/Main.aspx?page=Krasil_nikov_Sergejj_Aleksandrovich')
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), fromEncoding="utf-8")
>>> print soup.find('div', {'class': 'flagPageTitle'}).text
Красильников&nbsp;Сергей&nbsp;Александрович
```

As you can see, the words aren't separed with a regular space, but with a html space (`&nbsp;` or non breaking space). Using `.split('&nbsp;')` you could solve your problem:

```
>>> full_name = soup.find('div', {'class': 'flagPageTitle'}).text.strip().split('&nbsp;')
>>> len(full_name)
3
>>> for s in full_name: print s
... 
Красильников
Сергей
Александрович
```

Comment: It wasn't me -- I've never downvoted anyone -- but it's probably because the words aren't separated by semicolons but by the nbsp marker, the last character of which is a semicolon.  Your split is wrong.

Comment: @DSM You're absolutely right! damn, I didn't realize that. Now is fixed and I hope I can reverse those downvotes :(

Answer (score 1):

WIth python 3, to remove a &nbsp:

```
text = TEXT_WITH_NBSP.replace('\xa0','')
print(text)
```

Comment: Why remove these completely?  Wouldn't it be better to replace with a normal space character?  That way the eventual splitting that the OP wanted to do will work as expected

Answer (score 0):

Because your string is split by `&nbsp;` not spaces.

```
>>> full_name = soup.find('div', {'class': 'flagPageTitle'}).text.strip()
>>> full_name
u'\u041a\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0438\u043b\u044c\u043d\u0438\u043a\u043e\u0432&nbsp;\u0421\u0435\u0440\u0433\u0435\u0439&nbsp;\u0410\u
043b\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0430\u043d\u0434\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0438\u0447'

>>> full_name.split("&nbsp;")
[u'\u041a\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0438\u043b\u044c\u043d\u0438\u043a\u043e\u0432', u'\u0421\u0435\u0440\u0433\u0435\u0439', u'\u0410\u0
43b\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0430\u043d\u0434\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0438\u0447']
>>> len(full_name.split("&nbsp;"))
3
```

Comment: The downvote is because it isn't ; that separates his parts, it's `&nbsp;`

Comment: @NedBatchelder: Thanks. Otherwise I would have got atleast 10 downvotes if you had not corrected me.Don't know how i missed that `&nbsp`.

Comment: @NedBatchelder ... and that's why you always have to leave a comment after you downvote

Comment: @julio.alegria I totally agree with you.